# image size in ratio with div size without any stretch

Tags: html, css

Lets say I have a div of heigh 400px and width 400px.

```
<div style="width:400px; height:400px; background:#CCC;" align="center">
<img src="/static/{{media_info.media_file}}" />
</div>
```

Now if I have a image of height 350 and width 200 px I want it to be adjusted in this div. I mean it adjust inside the div being child to the div. It should not fit to the div neither stretch. Just fit in the center.

Like div should be taken as 100% and image should be in its ratio.

Remaining 50 px in height and 200 px in width should be left. like buttom and top leaving 25 25 px and left and right leaving 100 100 px.

Also if the image is of say width 800px and height 700 px same way the div  height and width should be considered as 100 percent and the image should lie in the middle without any stretch

I am not a front end developer :(

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `transform` property of css.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/89a0h98c/2/)

```
div {
    position: relative;
}
img {
    display: block;
    margin:0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: can you write the css inline

Comment: This too needs `overflow:hidden` for the div, otherwise an oversized image will break out of the it.

Comment: @aryan Yes, I can. It seems you know how to write inline because you know it is known as "inline" and a basic googler can know how to write it. (_It is not rocket science_). BTW, I might have thought to write it if you would have requested. I don't want to be rude with you but please show a little effort here. cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

So you want the image to be centered inside the div, in its original size, and any overflow simply cut of when the image is larger than the div in any dimension?

Well you could just set it as a centered background-image, instead of using in actual `img` element.

If that’s not an option, position it absolutely – `-50%` from either “side” (`top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom`), and use `margin:auto` to center it:

```css
div { position:relative; width:400px; height:400px; margin:10px; background:#ccc;
  overflow:hidden; }
div img { position:absolute; top:-50%; left:-50%; right:-50%;
   bottom:-50%; margin:auto; }
```

```html
<div id="div1"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/ff9999/000000"></div>
<div id="div2"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x700/ff9999/000000"></div>
```

Comment: Just curious, why didn't you just mention the values as `0`? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/yyzsbLhf/1/)

Comment: why is here 2 images ?

Comment: @Mr_Green: Because that doesn’t work for the horizontal centering of the oversized image (at least in Chrome and Opera, other browsers not checked)

Comment: @aryan: _“why is here 2 images ?”_  – because I wanted to demonstrate both cases – image smaller than div, and image larger than div …

Answer (score 1):

Note, I cleaned up the inline styles, just to make it clear.

http://jsfiddle.net/s4ja2q1z/4/

```
div {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: lime;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** Added fixes if the image is taller than the container.

Comment: can you please write in inline ? I need it inline

Comment: @aryan and you also an option to use <style>...</style> for inline css

Answer (score 0):

Try putting max-width and max-height on the image:

```
<img style="max-width: 100%;max-height: 100%;" src="/static/{{media_info.media_file}}" />
```

This will keep the image dimensions limited to a maximum width and height of the parent container (aka 400px in this case) and it will scale down if you ever change your parent div's dimensions without changing any ratios that would cause stretching.

Comment: Your answer is better than mine. Just one thing for @aryan: please, please, PLEASE don't use the "align" property. It's been deprecated since HTML 4.01.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my comment. That was meant for @aryan. He was using it.

Comment: This does not center the image vertically and horizontally as the OP requested.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way too by using the table-cell property.

> http://codepen.io/Edrees21/pen/XJoEmp

```
<div class="container">
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x200/aEEAEE" />
</div>

.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: This doesn’t work for an image that is larger than the div, like the 800×700 mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would set the image as a `background` of your `div` and then change the size of it using `background-size: contain`.

This will make your image not be distorted, but still fill the entire div.

`<div style="width:400px; height:400px; background-image:url("image.jpeg");    background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size: contain; background-position: center;">
</div>`

Answer (score -1):

```
div {
    text-align: center;
}

img {
    max-width: 400px;
    max-height: 400px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```